# MSAL and ADFS several resources

Tags: adfs, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have ADFS 2019. I created group application and two Web API.
I want to have Angular App that request token from ADFS and authorize for two APIs

so i use MSAL (which supports ADFS 2019 now). and I set requested scopes as array of two API identifiers, f.e:

```
authRequest: {
  scopes: ['https://api1.local//openid','https://api2.local//openid']
}
```

ADFS returns error MSIS9721 (it didnt expected more than one resource.
And it works fine if I leave one API identifier in `scope` array.

So question:
How to deal with more than one API using MSAL and ADFS?

Is it the only solution to have one API identifier that will be used by all .net project and define scopes and then assigning aloowable scopes to clients of that one huge API in ADFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access tokens are scoped to a single resource. If you need tokens for more than 1 resource you need to make separate requests for each.

Comment: mb you have experince in such situations? shouldn't user be authenticated twice or triple if we have two or three api?

Comment: No, authentication != authorization. You authenticate once and then as long as the user has consented to the scopes for each API you can use acquireTokenSilent to silently acquire tokens for each with separate requests.